# Взять значения из select и input и вставить в блок div. Обновление при изменении данных

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице есть два блока, в каждом из них содержится select и input.
Мне необходимо данные из них поместить в нужный мне блок в виде текстовой строки.

каждый select состоит из такого кода:

```
<div class="rselected" name="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="idfirst2" value="13" />
                <div class="rselecttitle">
                    <div class="rselecttitlevn">
                        <div class="rselectico" style="background: url(https://сайт.ру) no-repeat center center"></div>
                        <div class="rselectname">НАЗВАНИЕ1</div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

у них одинаковый код, но они отличаются name (1,2).

input имеют следующий код:

```
<div class="changewoerr">
                        <input type="text" name="summ1" id="wsumm1" class="rinput" value="16">
                        <div class="wowarnerr"></div>
                    </div>
```

и отличаются name(summ1, summ2).

Мне нужно получить следующую строку:

```
<div id="my_kurs" class="obminfo">Разница между значениями (сюда скопировать value из первого input) (здесь значение из первого select) = (value из второго input) (значение из второго select)</div>
```

При изменении значений в select1 меняются все данные в input-ах и втором селекте. Нужно что бы и данные менялись в формируемой строке без обновления страницы.

Comment: А вопрос то где?

Comment: Перечитал несколько раз и всё равно ничего не понял.. Переформулируйте вопрос и\или добавьте примеров (хотя бы скринов) желаемого результата..